# Filter and keep first object of a List of objects with properties that match

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I apologize upfront, because I now realize that I have completely worded my example wrong. For those who have given responses, I truly appreciate it. Please let me re-attempt to explain with a more accurate details. Please edit your responses, and once again, I apologize for not being more exact in my previous posting.

Using an entity framework model class called Staging (which is a representation of my Staging table), I have the following `List<Staging>`.

```
List<Staging> data = (from t in database.Stagings select t).ToList();
//check for an empty List...react accordingly...
```

Here is a quick look at what `Staging` looks like:

```
public partial class Staging
{
    public int ID { get; set; }        //PK
    public int RequestID { get; set; } //FK
    ...
    public string Project { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Let us suppose that the query returns 10 records into my `data` list. Let us also suppose that `data[3]`, `data[6]`, and `data[7]` each have the same value in `data.Project`, let's say `"Foo"`. The `data.Project` value is not known until runtime.

Given this, how would I keep the first occurrence, `data[3]`, and remove `data[6]` and `data[7]` from my `List<Staging>`?

**Edit:**
I have the following code that works, but is there another way?

```
  HashSet<string> projectValuesFound = new HashSet<string>();
  List<Staging> newData = new List<Staging>();

  foreach (Staging entry in data)
  {
    if (!projectValuesFound.Contains(entry.Project))
    {
      projectValuesFound.Add(entry.Project);
      newData.Add(entry);
    }
  }
```

Comment: The answer is here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linq-distinct-on-a-particular-property

Answer (score 2):

You can do this via LINQ and a `HashSet<T>`:

```
var found = new HashSet<string>();
var distinctValues = theList.Where(mc => found.Add(mc.Var3));

// If you want to assign back into the List<T> again:
// theList = distinctValues.ToList();
```

This works because `HashSet<T>.Add` returns true if the value was not already in the set, and false if it already existed.  As such, you'll only get the first "matching" value for `Var3`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Linq:

```
var result = (from my in theList where my.Var3 == "Foo" select my).First();
```

If you *also* want to keep the other items, you can use [Distinct()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) instead of First().  To use Dictinct(), either `MyClass` must implement `IEquatable<T>`, or you must provide an `IEqualityComparer<T>` as shown in the MSDN link.

Comment: Not sure what you mean?  Distinct() requires an `IEqualityComparer<TSource>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var uniques = (from theList select theList.Var3).Distinct();
```

That will give you distinct values for all entries.

Comment: You have to provide an `IEqualityComparer<TSource>` to `Distinct()` for this to meet the OP's requirement (unless MyClass implements `IEquatable<T>`, which is not shown).

Comment: @EricJ. It will return distinct `Var3` values without comparer. The problem, of course, is that it will return `Var3` values not `MyClass` objects.

Answer (score 0):

The "canonical" way to do it would be to pass appropriately implemented comparer to [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx):

```
class Var3Comparer : IEqualityComparer<MyClass> {
    public int GetHashCode(MyClass obj) {
        return (obj.Var3 ?? string.Empty).GetHashCode();
    }
    public bool Equals(MyClass x, MyClass y) {
        return x.Var3 == y.Var3;
    }
}

// ...

var distinct = list.Distinct(new Var3Comparer());
```

Just beware that while current implementation seems to keep the ordering of the "surviving" elements, the documentation says it "returns an unordered sequence" and is best treated that way.

There is also a [Distinct overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) that doesn't require a comparer - it just assumes the [Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx) comparer, which in turn, will utilize the [IEquatable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) if implemented by `MyClass`.